# Avoid view constraints interfering with frame change

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am working on a slider that as it moves updates the value of a particular label. The bar in the slider has a vertical constraint to keep it just on top of another element, and another one to center it horizontally.

If I do not update the label, changing the bar's position with a `PanGestureRecognizer` works perfectly:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let meterView = recognizer.view {

        let minX = view.bounds.minX + meterView.bounds.width/2
        let maxX = view.bounds.maxX - meterView.bounds.width/2
        var resultingX = meterView.center.x + translation.x
        resultingX = resultingX < minX ? minX : resultingX
        resultingX = resultingX > maxX ? maxX : resultingX

        meterView.center = CGPoint(x: resultingX,
                              y: meterView.center.y)

        updateHeight(at: meterView.center.x/(maxX-minX))
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}

func updateHeight(at percentage: CGFloat) {
    let percentage = Float(percentage)
    heightLabel.text = String((maxHeight - minHeight)*percentage)
}
```

However, if I change the label at any point of that pan (during or at the end of it), the bar jumps back to the horizontal center, I imagine, because of the constraint.

If I eliminate the horizontal (or all) constraint(s) during the pan, then the bar jumps out of the screen completely as I do a slight pan.

Is there a way to avoid the controller from updating the bar view back into its constraint-defined position?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you set up your layout with constraints then do not mess with the frames of the views, change constraints instead. I'd suggest to revise your pan logic in order to update bar position using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the constraint that centers the bar, and change it to a left constraint relating `meterView` (I'm assuming `meterView` is the bar) to its superview width:

```
meterView.left equal to Superview.left + constant
```

Now create a reference to that constraint called `meterViewLeftConstraint` and in `handlePan`, update the `constant` property of the constraint to `resultingX`:

```
meterViewLeftConstraint.constant = resultingX
```

And you don't need to set the `center` now.

I also recommend you to use [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io) to make constraints, because the `NSLayoutConstraint` API is quite messy.

Comment: You can not update the multiplier of the constraint, it is a readonly property.

Comment: @pckill I didn't realise that. Edited.